# Print increment variable when printing multiple copies of a page

Tags: microsoft-word

I have got word document with a single page which i wish to print multiple copies[around 200],im trying to print the COPY number on the each page it prints.Is this possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the Printer, this can be achieved by the Print dialog box.
There is a setting that would allow you to print the "Copy Set Number".

In Word2003 the option is under
File->Print
Click on Properties Button
Goto Finishing Tab
Click Finishing Details
Check Box "Copy Set Numbering"